# ¿Cómo puedo interpretar el valor de int(1 + num **0.5) dentro del rango de un ciclo for para la evaluación de números primos)?

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en Python, y hubo un ejercicio en particular que me dejo una duda. Tenía que crear una función que me permitiera saber si un número era primo. Logré resolver el ejercicio, pero al consultar la solución propuesta por el curso me dió esta solución, y me dejo con una gran duda. Dentro del **range()** del ciclo **for** dentro de la función y es que aún no comprendo este pequeño fragmento:

**int(1 + num ^0.5)**

El ejercicio fue este:

Tu tarea es escribir una función que verifique si un número es primo o no.

La función:

```
Se llama isPrime.
Toma un argumento (el valor a verificar).
Devuelve True si el argumento es un número primo, y False de lo contrario.
```

Sugerencia: intenta dividir el argumento por todos los valores posteriores (comenzando desde 2) y verifica el resto: si es cero, tu número no puede ser un número primo; analiza cuidadosamente cuándo deberías detener el proceso.

Si necesitas conocer la raíz cuadrada de cualquier valor, puedes utilizar el operador **. Recuerda: la raíz cuadrada de x es la misma que x0.5

```
def isPrime(num):
     for i in range(2, int(1 + num ** 0.5)):
          if num % i == 0:
               return False
     return True
        
for i in range(1, 20):
    if isPrime(i + 1):
        print(i + 1, end=" ")
#print(isPrime(19)) Devuelve True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por cierto, `num ** 0.5` es la forma de calcular la raíz cuadrada.

Si un número N es compuesto (no es primo), se puede descomponer en dos factores, P y Q, tales que:

```
N = P * Q
```

¿Qué valores pueden tomar P y Q? Si uno es grande, el otro tendrá que ser pequeño. Entonces, al menos uno de ellos tiene que ser menor o igual a la raíz cuadrada de N. Ambos no pueden ser mayores, obviamente.

Entonces no tiene sentido recorrer todo el rango hasta N - 1 para chequear si es primo o no. Si es un número compuesto, tienes que encontrar un factor en el rango raiz_cuadrada(N). Si no lo encuentras en ese rango, tiene que ser primo.

A la raíz cuadrada le sumas 1 para asegurarte de cubrir el rango completo.

El problema es que calcular raíz cuadrada es costoso. En su lugar puedes iterar hasta N / 2, que sólo te cuesta una división por dos.